# Google Cloud Functions with socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-run

My understanding is that to establish a persistent socket connection using socket.io the Node.js server should be always running. With Google Cloud Functions there isn't an always running  Node.js server, so keeping a socket connection alive is not possible.

Is Cloud Run with a running Node.js server the best option to handle multiple socket connections using socket.io ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE**: From January 2021, GCP Cloud Run supports WebSockets.

[Here is the link to the Cloud Run documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/triggering/websockets)

[Here is the link to the blog post (their announcement)](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/cloud-run-gets-websockets-http-2-and-grpc-bidirectional-streams)