# How to connect to Websocket server after deploying Firestore functions

Tags: express, google-cloud-firestore, websocket, google-cloud-functions

I have an API made with ExpressJS and Firestore, and a client-side made with React Native. I am using WebSockets to pass some real-time data. Everything works perfectly fine on my local server. Specifically, the WebSocket URL I am using to do a handshake is "http://192.168.86.39:7000". However, this has to be changed when this API is deployed to Firestore functions. How will I know the new WebSocket URL to use? The API URL has changed now from "http://192.168.86.39/" to "https://us-central1-APPNAME.cloudfunctions.net/app".

Code on how I made the Websocket server:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
server.listen(7000);
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your Cloud Function does. Are you trying to host a web socket server in Cloud Functions? If so, that will likely not work as Cloud Functions are made to run short-lived processes. For more on this, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45741284/run-a-web-socket-on-cloud-functions-for-firebase, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56903043/is-it-a-good-idea-to-run-socket-io-on-a-firebase-cloud-function/56906212#56906212 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/59771807

Comment: I'm trying to host an API server made with ExpressJS, and on that server, there is another server for WebSocket connection. I've added a code snippet on how I created the server for the WebSocket connection.

Comment: Thanks for that code sample  That's the scenario that is not going t be a great fit - as Cloud Functions are short-lived processes. Cloud Run might be a better fit for this. Have a look at the links I provided in my first comment, as they cover it quite well.